# Perceptron Model in C++ not Converging

Tags: c++, machine-learning

So I was writing a simple Perceptron model and when I finished the code and saw that there were no errors I was pretty surprised. But it seems like my model doesn't converge (along with some other oddities).

Basically it keeps getting 25/100 samples right at every epoch. And when every epoch ends the weights are always coming back to 0.

Due to the fact that the code is on multiple files I put it on Google Drive here it is: 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_r3mf9HbUrLaDNlc1F6RXhNMnM&usp=sharing

It is a Visual Studio Community 2013 project. You can open and run it so that you get a better idea.

Here's a quick preview of the files though.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h> 

#include "LinearAlgebra.h"
#include "MachineLearning.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace LinearAlgebra;
using namespace MachineLearning;

void printVector(vector< vector<float> > X);
vector< vector<float> > getIrisX();
vector<float> getIrisy();

int main()
{
    vector< vector<float> > X = getIrisX();
    vector<float> y = getIrisy();
    vector<float> test1;
    test1.push_back(5.0);
    test1.push_back(3.3);
    test1.push_back(1.4);
    test1.push_back(0.2);

    vector<float> test2;
    test2.push_back(6.0);
    test2.push_back(2.2);
    test2.push_back(5.0);
    test2.push_back(1.5);

    //printVector(X);
    //for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++){ cout << y[i] << " "; }cout << endl;

    perceptron clf(0.1, 10);
    clf.fit(X, y);
    cout << "Now Predicting: 5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2(CorrectClass=1,Iris-setosa) -> " << clf.predict(test1) << endl;
    cout << "Now Predicting: 6.0,2.2,5.0,1.5(CorrectClass=-1,Iris-virginica) -> " << clf.predict(test2) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void printVector(vector< vector<float> > X)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < X[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << X[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

vector<float> getIrisy()
{
    vector<float> y;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("y.data");
    string sampleClass;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        inFile >> sampleClass;
        if (sampleClass == "Iris-setosa")
        {
            y.push_back(1);
        }
        else
        {
            y.push_back(-1);
        }
    }

    return y;
}

vector< vector<float> > getIrisX()
{
    ifstream af;
    ifstream bf;
    ifstream cf;
    ifstream df;
    af.open("a.data");
    bf.open("b.data");
    cf.open("c.data");
    df.open("d.data");

    vector< vector<float> > X;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        char scrap;
        int scrapN;
        af >> scrapN;
        bf >> scrapN;
        cf >> scrapN;
        df >> scrapN;

        af >> scrap;
        bf >> scrap;
        cf >> scrap;
        df >> scrap;
        float a, b, c, d;
        af >> a;
        bf >> b;
        cf >> c;
        df >> d;
        X.push_back(vector < float > {a, b, c, d});
    }

    af.close();
    bf.close();
    cf.close();
    df.close();

    return X;
}
```

MachineLearning.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

namespace MachineLearning{

    class perceptron
    {
    public:
        perceptron(float eta,int epochs);
        float netInput(vector<float> X);
        int predict(vector<float> X);
        void fit(vector< vector<float> > X, vector<float> y);
    private:
        float m_eta;
        int m_epochs;
        vector < float > m_w;
        vector < float > m_errors;
    };

}
```

MachineLearning.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <math.h> 

#include "MachineLearning.h"

using namespace std;

namespace MachineLearning{

    perceptron::perceptron(float eta, int epochs)
    {
        m_epochs = epochs;
        m_eta = eta;
    }

    void perceptron::fit(vector< vector<float> > X, vector<float> y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < X[0].size() + 1; i++) // X[0].size() + 1 -> I am using +1 to add the bias term
        {
            m_w.push_back(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m_epochs; i++)
        {
            int errors = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < X.size(); j++)
            {
                float update = m_eta * (y[j] - predict(X[j]));
                m_w[0] = update;
                for (int w = 1; w < m_w.size(); w++){ m_w[w] = update * X[j][w - 1]; }
                errors += update != 0 ? 1 : 0;
            }
            m_errors.push_back(errors);
        }
    }

    float perceptron::netInput(vector<float> X)
    {
        // Sum(Vector of weights * Input vector) + bias
        float probabilities = m_w[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++)
        {
            probabilities += X[i] * m_w[i + 1];
        }
        return probabilities;
    }

    int perceptron::predict(vector<float> X)
    {
        return netInput(X) > 0 ? 1 : -1; //Step Function
    }

}
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Panos P.

Comment: Before diving in the code... did you check if the dataset linearly separable? (Honestly, I'd rather do this in MATLAB or other high level language. Verifying visually using plots can make life a lot easier.)

Comment: Perceptron guarantees convergence if and only if dataset are linearly separable

Comment: I am using the iris dataset which is linearly separable. I have implemented the code in python as well and it worked fine. Also if the problem was that it wouldn't converge wouldn't it at least have different errors in each epoch? I think that this in combination with the weights changing back to 0 at the end of every epoch denotes that there must be something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of tedious debugging I finally found the mistake. There was a bug in my code when I updated the weights.

```
for (int j = 0; j < X.size(); j++)
        {
            float update = m_eta * (y[j] - predict(X[j]));
            m_w[0] = update;
            for (int w = 1; w < m_w.size(); w++){ m_w[w] = update * X[j][w - 1]; }
            errors += update != 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }
```

notice that:

```
m_w[w] = update * X[j][w - 1]
```

I am setting the weights as equal to the update. It looks like I forgot a "+" sign. Now it works fine.

Here's it is now:

```
m_w[w] += update * X[j][w - 1]
```

Sometimes the silliest mistakes can cause the most annoying of errors.
I hope that this might help anyone making the same mistake.